# How can I watermark a DateField control in Flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I would like to know how to make a DateField control with a watermark. I want to set the prompt/watermark text from MXML like this one:

```
<mx:DateField id="id_date" propmt="Select date" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<mx:DateField id="df" text="Select Date"  focusIn="df.text=''" />
```

OR 
Refer This Blog for custom datefield component
[WaterMarkDateField](http://flexsupport.blogspot.com/2011/11/watermark-datefield.html)

Comment: But when we select some date and then focus In it also remove our selected date.

Comment: @Tahir Alvi Then Dont use `focusIn="df.text=''"` If you can just try WaterMarkDateField component.

Answer (score 0):

Its Quite Simple by using the creation complete handler

```
<mx:DateField id="sample" creationComplete="sample_creationCompleteHandler(event)"/>
```

set the sample text like this

```
protected function sample_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sample.text = "Select Date";
}
```

Try this..

Comment: But Sudharsanan, This is not a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

I have done like following way. Don't know it's correct way or not. But, it's working for me.

```
<mx:DateField id="dateIdentify" editable="true" selectedDate="new Date()" formatString="MM-DD-YYYY" color="#505050" focusOut="if(dateIdentify.text == ''){dateIdentify.text='MM-DD-YYYY'}" focusIn="if(dateIdentify.text == '' || dateIdentify.text == 'MM-DD-YYYY'){dateIdentify.text='';}" text="MM-DD-YYYY"/>
```

Hope it helps someone.