# flex - How to set prompt for DateField component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a `DateField` in my application. And I want to set prompt for `DateField` Textinput. I need it like spark `TextField` prompt.  I tried something. But I am not satisfied with it.

Anybody can tell me about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I watermark a DateField control in Flex 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005602/how-can-i-watermark-a-datefield-control-in-flex-4)

Comment: I already saw this one. But I need some other. Is it any other way?

Comment: Check this one: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.datefield.html. Search for "Input Prompt" in this page.

Comment: It's fairly easy to create a hybrid component: extend Spark TextField (which has the prompt feature), make it readOnly and make it pop up an mx [DateChooser](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/controls/DateChooser.html) component when the user clicks on the field.